# how to set cursor position in a textarea back on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a textarea, after hitting the enter button the text get processed and the textarea get resetted by .val(''); (jquery).

But the cursor is still in the second line of the textarea...

How to set the cursor position back on top? using jquery or plain javascript...

Comment: May be you have some spaces there?

Answer (score 4):

Random guess, but yes if you reset the content in a keydown/press after an enter *key*, then you will get a blank line at the top .. as you just pressed the enter key.

Kill it:

```
$('#tarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).val('').focus();    
        return false;
    }        
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set back cursor position to the top of the textbox then you need to kill the current event like keydown/keypress. When you reset the content in a keydown/press after an enter key, then you will get a blank line at the top .. as you just pressed the enter key.

Kill it using below code:

```
$('#tarea').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    $(this).val('').focus();    
    return false;
  }        
});?
```